# Make cypress type an empty space(spacebar) while holding shift

Tags: cypress

I have to type into a autocomplete menu where if cypress types a spacebar, it closes the autocomplete.

So if the option i want is "Option good" and there are also: "Option bad" and "Option not"

It will escape the menu at the first space and wont let me continue typing the option I want.

How can I do it so that instead of typing a regular spacebar, it does it with shift+spacebar?

Thanks.

Comment: `"{shift} "`? Did you read https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/type.html

Answer (score -1):

I did it like this:

```
const currentProviderNameWords = currentProviderName.split(' ');
currentProviderNameWords.forEach((word, i) =>  {
  getAndLog(".mat-select-filter-input[placeholder='Suche']").type(word);
  if (i < currentProviderNameWords.length -1) getAndLog(".mat-select-filter-input[placeholder='Suche']").type("{shift} ");
});
```